# copy and paste cell value from one sheet to another onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a google script to create and paste the values from a cell in one sheet to another (same spreadsheet). The code consists of following two steps:

1. (works): If a cell of specific columns of one sheet are edited, then the next adjacent cell gets a value based on the edit.
2. (does not work): Paste the new value of the adjacent cell into the cell of the next empty row (1st column) in the second sheet.

The code below is what I have tried so far, but the value does not appear on the second sheet. Does anybody know where the problem is in my attempt below?

Thx

```
function onEdit() {
 var a = [19,21,23]
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "ALL" ) {
   var valActive = s.getActiveCell();
   var col = valActive.getColumn();
   var row = valActive.getRow();
   var range = s.getRange(row, 1);
   var val0 = range.getValue();
   if( a.indexOf(col) > -1 && valActive.getValue() != '') {
    var nextCell = valActive.offset(0, 1);
    var val1 = valActive.getValue();
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "GMT+1", "HHmm");
     nextCell.setValue(val0 + '_' + val1 + '_' + time);
    var rowNext = nextCell.getRow();
    var colNext = nextCell.getColumn();
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Samples");
    var lastRow = target.getLastRow();
    s.getRange(rowNext, colNext).copyTo(target.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: rename your function to `onEdit(e)` and use that [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)! That will let you get rid of ambiguous and incorrect usage of `getActive....`

Comment: @tehhowch Can you elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: What's to say? Accessing the "active" states of a workbook from an on-edit triggered function is wrong. There is no guarantee that the active sheet, cell, workbook, or value has not changed between the event emission time and the time at which the function runs.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I still don't understand why step1 works and step2 does not work. However, I shall try to incorporate your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To get the second part to work you want to append a row to your other sheet. Try something like this:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Name");
  sheet.appendRow([newValue]);
```